# XSLT: How to change the tag name if it's parent or child node?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm having this xml as my input :

```
        <unidad num="2.">
               <tag></tag>
               <tag2></tag2>
       <unidad num="2.1">
                  <tag></tag>
                  <tag2></tag2>          
                  <unidad num="2.1.1">
                     <tag></tag>
                     <tag2></tag2>  
                     <unidad num="2.1.1.1">
                        <tag></tag>
                        <tag2></tag2>   
                     </unidad>
                  </unidad>
               </unidad>
            </unidad>
```

My output should be :

```
        <sub>
               <tag></tag>
               <tag2></tag2>
       <sub2>
                  <tag></tag>
                  <tag2></tag2>          
                  <sub3>
                     <tag></tag>
                     <tag2></tag2>  
                     <sub4>
                        <tag></tag>
                        <tag2></tag2>   
                     </sub4>
                  </sub3>
               </sub2>
            </sub>
```

I can't find the proper way to do this. I'm working with templates, i'm having this :

```
  <xsl:for-each select="unidad">
        <xsl:call-template name="unidades1"/>
  </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:template name="unidades1">
    <xsl:element name="sub1">
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
           <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::*"/>
    </xsl:if>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="unidad">
           <xsl:call-template name="unidades2"/>
       </xsl:template>


      <xsl:template name="unidades2">
    <xsl:element name="sub2">
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
           <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::*"/>
    </xsl:if>
       </xsl:template>
```

With this XSLT, every child of unidad matches the second condition, so it's written as sub2, and I don't know how to consider if it is a child of another unidad element.  Any ideas how to reach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet produces the desired output. It uses a modified [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) with a specialized template for the `<unidad>` elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<!--standard identity template-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="unidad">
<!--count the number of ancestors that are unidad elements-->
        <xsl:variable name="unidad-ancestor-count" select="count(ancestor::unidad)"/>

<!--If there are at least one unidad ancestors then 
    set the suffix to be the count()+1-->  
      <xsl:variable name="suffix">
            <xsl:if test="$unidad-ancestor-count>0">
                <xsl:value-of select="$unidad-ancestor-count+1"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>

<!--create a new element using a base name of "sub" and the suffix value -->
        <xsl:element name="sub{$suffix}">
<!--not pushing the @num attribute through the identity template, 
    just descendant nodes-->
            <xsl:apply-templates /> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```